# Bash for loop prints unexpected output, why is that?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I wrote a script which queries a dns zone on AWS Route53 and returns IP's of specific servers.

The aim is to run this script after starting a CloudFormation stack and that the script will update my local `~/.ssh/config` file with the updated servers IP's.

I want to "catch" the line in the config which starts with HostName but related to the hostname of the server I would like to edit and so I've ran the following command:

```
$ grep -A2 dev-api2.company-private ~/.ssh/config
Host dev-api2.company-private
User ec2-user
HostName 5.5.5.5
```

Next, I've ran:

```
$ for line in $(grep -A2 dev-api2.company-private ~/.ssh/config); do echo $line  ; done
Host
dev-api2.company-private
User
ec2-user
HostName
5.5.5.5
```

For some reason the output is printed not as I expected, it broke each word to a separate line, but why does it happen?

Edit #1:
My idea was to do something like that:

```
for line in $(grep -A2 dev-api2.company-private ~/.ssh/config)
do
    if [[ $line == "^HostName.*" ]]
    then
        sed -i 's!$line!HostName 1.1.1.1!g' ~/.ssh/config
    fi
done
```

Edit #2:
Ok, so the relevant portion of the `~/.ssh/config` file looks like that:

```
Host as-bastion
User ec2-user
HostName ec2-34.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company/bastion.pem

Host dev-api1.company-private
User ec2-user
HostName 172.51.24.171
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company/company.pem
ProxyCommand ssh ec2-user@as-bastion -W %h:%p

Host dev-api2.company-private
User ec2-user
HostName 172.51.25.248
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company/company.pem
ProxyCommand ssh ec2-user@as-bastion -W %h:%p
```

The file contains many blocks like the ones above, but I want to sed only the "HostName" lines of blocks which contain the string I've used in the grep (dev-api2.company-private).

@anubhava: The code in your answer changed lines containing the string "HostName" even in blocks which are not related to "dev-api2.company-private".

How can it be done?

Comment: Read  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using this `while read` loop using *process substitution* instead of a `for` loop using *command substitution*:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(grep -A2 dev-api2.company-private ~/.ssh/config)
```

---

Based on your comments I suggest it is better to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v api='^Host dev-api2' -v ip='1.1.1.1' '
$0 ~ api "\\.company-private$" {sub(/\nHostName [^\n]+/, "\nHostName " ip)} 1' ~/.ssh/config
```

To save changes use this `awk` command:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v api='^Host dev-api2' -v ip='1.1.1.1' '
$0 ~ api "\\.company-private$" {sub(/\nHostName [^\n]+/, "\nHostName " ip)} 1
' ~/.ssh/config > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp ~/.ssh/config
```

---

Here is one liner `sed` to do the same job:

```
sed -i.bak '/dev-api2\.company-private/{N;p;N;s/.*/HostName 1.1.1.1/;}' ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `sed: 1: "/Users/itai/.ssh/config": command i expects \ followed by text`, Do you know how to fix it? and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Yes, I’ve inserted your code to a file with a bash shebang and ran it, on my mac.

Comment: The `~.*~` would of changed all of the lines which contain "HostName" to "HostName 1.1.1.1", I've fixed the search pattern, but it did exactly that anyways... good thing Mac requires you to set a `.bak` otherwise I would of lost the file as I forgot to back it up :) Any ideas?

Comment: It still changes more than one line containing the "HostName" string and not the only line which is exactly 2 lines below this line: "Host dev-api2.company-private" - it changed the HostName line in all 3 blocks which I've added to the question earlier.

Comment: Perfect! You're awesome.

Comment: If I wanted "dev-api2" and "1.1.1.1" to be represented by variables, let's say $hn and $privip , how would the awk line look?

Comment: @ItaiGanot: You may use: `awk -v api='dev-api2' -v ip='1.1.1.1' '$0 ~ api "\.company-private"{p=NR}
p && NR==p+2 && /^HostName/{$0="HostName " ip; p=0} 1' ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the valuable hint. I have updated answer with an `awk` command using `v RS=`